# How would I find the average value of a function over a given interval?

Tags: calculus

How would I find the average value of this function?
$$f(x)=\sin(nx),\ 0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{n}$$
Where n is a positive integer. I am not sure how I would solve this thank you.

Comment: The average value of the function is given by the the area under the graph for the interval divided by the length of the interval

Answer (score 1):

Here, the average value $\overline{y}$ is 
\begin{align}
\overline{y}&=\frac{1}{\pi/n}\int_0^{\pi/n}\sin(nx)\;dx\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{ \pi/n}\sin (nx)\,ndx\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin t\;dt\qquad\qquad\text{being }t=nx\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{2}{\pi}}
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure I understand, can you please explain your result?

Comment: @CarlosV: The average value of a function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\;dx$$
Then, you must evaluate such integral for the given function for the corresponding interval.

Answer (score 0):

The area under sine curve $ y = \sin x $ in the interval is 2 for interval $ 0<x<\pi $and average vale $2/\pi$, the way question is asked average value is independent of $n$.